# combine three measures into one dimension in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

I have a set of data, dimension is time and three measures are global medium temperature, north sphere temperature and south sphere temperate, and I want to show this set of data as this form which is for each year, it has one bar made by three pieces(global, north, south) but the thing is I don't want them added together, I want them show that (south + north)/2 = global, so the global should always be at the middle of bar and one is lower and another is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put measure names on the columns shelf to the right of Year